# Calculate accuracy of word2vec model in Python

Tags: python, word2vec

I want to get the accuracy from the Doc2Vec model implemented in Python.
I saw in the official documentation that there is a method to get the accuracy, which takes as parameter a file. What should be the content of that input file?

I tried to put 4-tuple as documentation says, but I get all the patterns misclassified.

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple measurement of a Doc2Vec model's accuracy – you'd need to have a evaluation method that's custom to your corpus and project goals.

The `accuracy()` method on Word2Vec, also inherited by Doc2Vec, does a very narrow kind of analogy-testing, using word-vectors only, because the same method was used in the original word2vec paper and original Google word2vec.c toolkit. You can see the test-files they used, `questions-words.txt` and `questions-phrases.txt`, in a [Github mirror of the Google word2vec-toolkit](https://github.com/tmikolov/word2vec).

Since some Doc2Vec modes generate word-vectors, you could do this sort of analogy test on those Doc2Vec models – but it doesn't check the document-vectors at all, and a model that does well on those word-analogies might not be best for whatever your downstream document task is.